# Hook a specific function in a dll

Tags: c++, c, dll, process, hook

Is it possible to hook all the processes, or find out when a specific function in a dll is called? I want to be able to catch this call and inject my own code / deny access to this function. How can I do this without looping through all the processes and hook each one of them?
Is it possible to do so without altering system files? (I'm planning on doing this on an android device and I don't want to require a root)

Comment: Wait, you want to do this on Android, but you talk about DLL...? Sounds contradictory to me, DLLs are a Windows concept. Do you mean dynamic libraries in general (including `.so`, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Simply write a dll with the same ABI.

The idea is to make you dll call the equivalent functions from the original dll, eventually adding a special process, or do nothing or report an unauthorized call if necessary.

Comment: I forgot to add that I need to do so without altering the original dlls or changing system files. (I'm planning on doing so on android and I don't want to require a root).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this requirement.